# База знаний с системой теститрования

Tags: веб-программирование, web-apps, движок, moodle

Нужно организовать систему для предприятия с базой знаний типа wiki. При этом очень важной является возможность тестировать знания сотрудников. Тест в самом простом его виде - список вопросов и ответов.

При этом хотелось, чтобы сотрудники могли самостоятельно вписывать свои ответы на вопросы, если представленные в списке ответов варианты их не устраивают.

Естественно нужны возможности аутентификации и разграничения прав пользователей.

Посоветуйте готовые легкие платформы или движки для такой мини wiki (что-нибудь кроме moodle - слишком огромный и сложный).

Answer (score 2):

Для wiki не знаю, но как standalone приложение успешно использовал [itest](http://itest.sourceforge.net/)